# flutter // how used future and tip please

Tags: flutter, dart

I logged in and fetched the mainscreen.dart page, but I don't know how to declare and execute functions, and how to import and execute files from other class files

I logged in and fetched the mainscreen.dart page, but I don't know how to declare and execute functions, and how to import and execute files from other class files

```
///main_screen.dart

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mysql/model/user.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mysql/user/user_pref.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mysql/api/api.dart';
import 'package:flutter_mysql/model/locate.dart';

class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  const MainScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MainScreen> createState() => workcheck();
}


class workcheck extends State<MainScreen> {
  List<double> my_wichi = [];

  my_locate() async{
    Locate locator = Locate();

    // 위치 정보 가져오기
    List<double> location = await locator.get_loc();
  }
  // SharedPreferences로 받아온 데이터 가져오기
  getdata() async {
    List<String> userdata = [];
    User? userInfo = await RememberUser.getRememberUserInfo();
    if (userInfo != null) {
      // 사용자 정보를 성공적으로 가져온 경우
      // userInfo를 사용하여 원하는 작업을 수행합니다.
      userdata.add(userInfo.dep_name);
      userdata.add(userInfo.user_name);
      userdata.add(userInfo.user_id);
      return userdata;
    }
    return null; // 사용자 정보가 없는 경우 null 반환
  }

 btn_gowork() async{
    try{
      var res = await http.post(
          Uri.parse(API.gowork),
        body: {
        }
      );
      if(res.statusCode == 200) {
        var reswork = jsonDecode(res.body);
        if(reswork['success'] == true)
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "출근 성공");
      }
      else{
        Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "출근 실패");
      }
    }
    catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: e.toString());
    }
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // 함수 실행은 
    //요 부분에서
    return Scaffold(
      
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('출근하기')
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('1'),
              SizedBox(height: 30),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  btn_gowork();
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 40,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.lightBlue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 55.0),
                      child: Text('출근',textAlign: TextAlign.center,),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],

          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


///locate.dart

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class Locate{

  
  Future<List<double>> location() async {
    List<double> m_l = [];
    // 위치 권한 요청
    LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    // 현재 위치 가져오기
    Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
    // 위치 정보 리스트에 추가
    m_l.add(position.longitude);
    m_l.add(position.latitude);
    return m_l; // 위치 정보를 포함한 리스트 반환
  }

  Future<List<double>> get_loc() async {
    // 위치 정보를 가져오기
    List<double> location = await this.location(); // 수정된 부분
    return location; // 위치 정보를 포함한 리스트 반환
  }

}
```

I've been trying for a few days, but it's not working. Please help.